# Use ConfigService within `main.js` of Nest.js application

Tags: javascript, typescript, middleware, nestjs

I am trying to figure out how I can us my ConfigService [created as described here](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/configuration). Within the top-most level of my application.

My `main.js` file looks like this:

```
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { TypeormStore } from 'connect-typeorm';
import * as session from 'express-session';
import { getRepository } from 'typeorm';
import { Session } from '../../domains/session/Session';
import { AppModule } from './AppModule';

async function bootstrap() {
    const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);

    app.use(session({
        resave: false,
        saveUninitialized: false,
        store: new TypeormStore({
            cleanupLimit: 2,
            ttl: 86400
        }).connect(getRepository(Session)),
        secret: process.env.COOKIE_SECRET as string
    }))

    await app.listen(3000);
}
bootstrap();
```

What I'd like is to move `process.env.COOKIE_SECRET` to a getter inside `ConfigService`. Can I access services at this level?

Answer (score 8):

To pull any service out from the application context after the factory has created the application *(normally after `const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule)`)* you can then use the app's `.get()` method to pull out the service for use:

```
const config = app.get<ConfigService>(ConfigService);
```

From here, you can use the config methods you've created.